# How to align div's to center when size of adjacent div's overflows screen width

Tags: html, css, alignment

My question must be little bit confusing and will have many related questions. But I think my case is different.

Please **run the code in full screen** and reduce the size of the screen to around such that there will be

- Two boxes per row
- One box per row

In both cases there will be lot of empty space to right of the adjacent box, what I want is to align the box to the center and make look both right and left equal when such a case occurs. **It should work for both the cases (Two boxes per row & One box per row)**

```css
body{
background-color : #E9EAED;
}
.box{
 position: relative;
 width: 400px;
 float: left;
 border: 1px solid rgba(35, 173, 278, 1);
 height: 120px;
 background-color: white;  
 cursor: pointer;
 margin: 15px 15px 15px 15px;

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<div class="box">box 1 </div>
<div class="box">box 2 </div>
<div class="box"> box 3</div>
<div class="box"> box 4</div>
<div class="box">box 5 </div>
<div class="box">box 6 </div>
<div class="box"> box 7</div>
<div class="box"> box 8</div>
<div class="box"> box 9</div>
<div class="box"> box 10</div>
<div class="box">box 11 </div>
<div class="box">box 12 </div>
<div class="box"> box 13</div>
<div class="box"> box 14</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add to body

```
body {
text-align: center;
}
```

And change the box class

```
.box {
float: left; //remove this
display: inline-block; //add this
text-align: left; // that your text would be aligned normally again
}
```

Comment: Easiest way to align everything, without changing any widths. Glad it worked

Comment: @Frutis you should also inform the OP about `text-align: start` its browser support and cross browsing issue. As far as i've information, this is only an experimental API and lacks browser support...

Comment: @MuhammadUsman umm don't know much about that, I thought that `text-align` and `inline-block` have been with us for a long time. If you think that this is a big problem, then inform him. I will gladly take a look at that also.

Comment: @Frutis I'm about `start` value of `text-align` property. For more information you can follow this link https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/text-align

Comment: @MuhammadUsman good tutorial, thanks. Updated it to `left` now.

Comment: can you please explain how text-align: center; for body can affect the alignement  of that box ?

Comment: @neo `text-align` property can affect `inline` and `inline-block` elements but `block` elements are not affected by this. `float` css property makes elements `block` as well. so they can't be affected by `text-align` and we need to make them `inline-block` so that they can be `left`, `right` or `center` aligned...